# Recursion logic from Iterating over iterator and so on

Tags: java, recursion, iterator

Can anybody help me with recursion logic? I have a iterator object, on which I am iterating using while loop. Then in each iterated object I again have to iterate and so on.

```
private void handleRecursiveMethod(someMethod) {
                    Iterator<Sometype> methods=doingSomething(someMethod));
                    while(methods.hasNext()){
                        printingDetailsAboutThisMethod(methods.next())
                        // Again with each method I have to do same
                        // operation until methods.hasNext becomes false.
                        handleRecursiveMethod(methods.next());
                        // By calling this, it does not complete while
                        // loop first time.
                    }
}
```

Comment: You need a type for the parameter `someMethod` before you can do anything.

Comment: Just assume that there is some Type. I wanted to ask about recursion logic.

Comment: This isn't recursive logic. This is iterative logic. I'm confused by what you're asking.

Comment: I understand. See I have some methods in methods(Type: Iterator). Then I want to traverse through each method and while traversing I will again get some Methods like in first step I got. Then again with these methods I may get few more methods. So with each methods I need to call printingDetailsAboutThisMethod.  So how can I write the iteration or recursion logic to get each and every method of depth level.  Please help.

Comment: This is quite helpful.but this is what I was also trying.in this case if condition is true in first iteration then this logic will not look for other iterator object associated with it. I think This logic will work for if a object is having other object then traverse again but not when a object having many object and then traverse through each and every object and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your function goes into while loop till the iterator has no more entries to iterate on. So I think when you call `handleRecursiveMethod(methods.next());` at the end of the method, it should be throwing you a  `NoSuchElementException`.

From your example, it seems to be that you are trying to do a depth first traversal. So, your code should look something like

```
private void handleRecursiveMethod(Sometype someMethod) {
    Iterator<Sometype> methods=doingSomething(someMethod));
     while(methods.hasNext()){
          Sometype method = methods.next()
          printingDetailsAboutThisMethod(method)
          handleRecursiveMethod(method);
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 although your answer is only somewhat useful, though code was fixed correctly. It only throws `NoSuchElementException` if there are an odd number of values being iterated. Of course, only odd elements are given to `printingDetailsAboutThisMethod` and only even elements are used in the recursive call to `handleRecursiveMethod`, so your code fix is correct, but the description is a bit off.

Comment: This is quite helpful.but this is what I was also trying.in this case if condition is true in first iteration then this logic will not look for other iterator object associated with it. I think This logic will work for if a object is having other object then traverse again but not when a object having many object and then traverse through each and every object and so on.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by other objects associated with it ? The role of the iterator is to iterate through all objects within a collection. In this case, in the while loop, all elements in the collection someMethod will be traversed and for each of them the recursive function will be called. So, this should cover all elements in the tree. Could you please explain your question further ?